# Unable to drop/delete table in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm unable to delete the table, as it shows the error below:

> Drop failed for Table "dbo.CustomerTest"

[image]

Please advise what should I do to delete this table?

Comment: You've got a lock on the table somewhere else. Perhaps another transaction or an explicit lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lock happening on the table and you can find out the session locking the table using `sp_lock`.

Here, We are trying to mimic lock scenario.

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo.test(a INT) 

insert into test values(1),(2);

BEGIN TRANSACTION

update TEST set a = 3 where a =1
```

Now, if we call `sp_lock` in another session, we will come to know the session, which is apply lock.

```sql
declare @LOCKS table(
spid smallint, dbid smallint, objid int, indid smallint, type nchar(4), resource nchar(32),
mode nvarchar(8), status nvarchar(5))

insert into @locks
exec sp_lock
select spid, db_name(dbid) as databasename, OBJECT_NAME(objid) as tablename,type,resource,mode, status from @locks
```

| spid | databasename | tablename | type | resource | mode | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | WideWorldImporters | NULL | DB |  | S | GRANT |
| 60 | WideWorldImporters | test | RID | 3:8432:0 | X | GRANT |
| 60 | WideWorldImporters | test | PAG | 3:8432 | IX | GRANT |
| 60 | WideWorldImporters | test | TAB |  | IX | GRANT |

If you want to kill the session, you have to kill it accordingly.

```sql
kill 60 -- session holding lock on the table
```